# Block status update if current status X

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I have a function to update a post status as below,

```
public function update_post()
    {
        $this->is_allowed('api_$customer_id_driver_task_update', false);


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'trim|required|max_length[255]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

            $save_data = [
                'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
            ];

            $save_people_driver_task = $this->model_api_people_driver_task->change($this->post('task_id'), $save_data);

            if ($save_people_driver_task) {
                $this->response([
                    'status'    => true,
                    'message'   => 'Your data has been successfully updated into the database'
                ], API::HTTP_OK);

            } else {
                $this->response([
                    'status'    => false,
                    'message'   => cclang('data_not_change')
                ], API::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            }

        } else {
            $this->response([
                'status'    => false,
                'message'   => validation_errors()
            ], API::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }
    }
```

the status it self is assigned, onstart, completed. What i want to do is if the status already onstart, the script will block the user to change status revert back to assigned and also if status already completed user cannot change the status to onstart or assigned. is it possible to do this?

Already try something like this but no luck

```
if($result && $result[0]->status =='assigned') 
{ 
    $this->db->set('status','onstarts'); 
}
else
{ 
    $this->db->set('status','completed'); 
}
```

Comment: i see no mention of any of the status strings you just described. where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment i already add the if else status but not working. I will update the script on question